# Factoring a given quartic form

Tags: polynomials, factoring

### Description

Below is our polynomial:
$$3x^4-8x^3y+14x^2y^2-8xy^3+3y^4$$
I've gone to almost end of it but,it seems there's a small -or conversely huge- fault in my solving which made  $\mathbf{A}\:and\: \mathbf{B}$ **imaginary numbers** as I didn't find any two numbers which Could have the **sum** of $-8xy$ and **product** of $24x^2y^2$ OR in another sense , I can not find $\mathbf{A}\:and\: \mathbf{B}$.

### My work

$$\begin{align}
 & 3x^4-8x^3y+14x^2y^2-8xy^3+3y^4 \\
 & = 3(x^4+y^4)-8xy(x^2+y^2)+14x^2y^2 \\
 & = 3(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2)-8xy(x^2+y^2)+8x^2y^2\\
 & = 3(x^2+y^2)^2-8xy(x^2+y^2)+8x^2y^2\\
 & = \frac{1}{3}\times[3^2(x^2+y^2)^2-      3\times8xy(x^2+y^2)+24x^2y^2] \\
& =\frac{1}{3}(3(x^2+y^2)+\mathbf{A})(3(x^2+y^2)+\mathbf{B})
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by symmetry

$$(ax^2+bxy+cy^2)(cx^2+bxy+ay^2)=\\=acx^4+(ab+bc)x^3y+(a^2+b^2+c^2)x^2y^2+(ab+bc)xy^3+(ac)y^4$$

then we need

- $ac=3 \implies a=3\, c=1$
- $ab+bc=-8 \implies3b+b=-8\implies b=-2$
- $a^2+b^2+c^2=14 \implies 9+4+1=14$

thus

$$3x^4-8x^3y+14x^2y^2-8xy^3+3y^4=(3x^2-2xy+y^2)(x^2-2xy+3y^2)$$

Comment: It's totally right but, is there some approach by which we can solve for$ \mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$

Comment: Let $x=y=1$ and you get 
$$12 =(6+\mathbf{A})(6+\mathbf{B})$$


Let $x=-y=1$ and you get 
$$36 =(6+\mathbf{A})(6+\mathbf{B})$$

So there is no A and B.

Comment: Fine. Thank you